# Appending to combobox field in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I have a combobox with a text. When you select the element from the dropdown it must be appended to the field of the combobox but not replaced.

I've tried this:

```
beforeselect: function (combo, record) {
       var rawVal = this.rawValue;

       ...............


       record.data.Value = rawVal + record.data.Value;
}
```

But this code adds to the store modified version of record, so it is not what I need. I need store haven't modified.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question clearly, the field you need is tag field not combobox. You can check the example from below link.

http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/examples/kitchensink/#form-tag

You do not need to do any record operayion by using tag field. If you have any further question, let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, @yiley. But I've solved this with another way: on beforeselect event saved the full value of the textfield and then after select pasted that value into the textfield with the `setRawValue()` function.